# Junit fails because the Server$StartJob still running

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am running junit test on eclipse, all it does is, trying to start the server in debug mode. However, I am getting the following error:

"Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob "

there is a piece of code that is triggered from a thread and it wont hit unless the junit tests are all complete. but once the tests are done, it closes the workbench and  hence server startup job is never completed.

Is there a way to wait for the job to complete and then run junit test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join their family to make the executing thread block until all jobs in the family are done.

See `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobManager#join(Object, IProgressMonitor)` and 
`org.eclipse.wst.server.core.ServerUtil#SERVER_JOB_FAMILY`

Comment: Hey can u elaborate this solution more in detail ?

Comment: If you want the job to finish, assuming it will if given enough time, you want to make the unit test pause until the job is finished. The Jobs API, through the job manager, allows different jobs to say they're part of a "family", and for anyone else to block on a call to join() with the family ID to ensure that those jobs aren't running. So invoking `Job.getJobManager().join(ServerUtil.SERVER_JOB_FAMILY);` should halt the execution of the caller until that job is completed.

Comment: That was a perfect solution. It solved my problem.. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Be sure to Accept answers to your questions.