# check if path is absolute or not using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to determine if a path is absolute or not using regex (`Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

My requirements are:

1. path should start with any character followed by ":" and "\" (e.g C:)
2. it could start with "\"
3. it could start with "/"

I wrote this regex expresion: `"^((?i)[a-z]):\\.*"` but that doesn't seem to work.

I cannot use `path.isAbsolute` because I need a platform independent way of detecting absolute path.

Could you tell me what is wrong with that expression?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs for `isAbsolute()`?  That method seems platform independent to me.

Comment: why you failed to add the second and third rule in your regex?

Comment: could you post some examples for valid matches?

Comment: Are you required to use a regex?  You could use File.getCanonicalPath() instead.  I am not sure why you say File.isAbsolute() is not platform independent.  In fact, it sounds like you want a method for Windows machines (platform dependent), rather than platform-independent.

Comment: actually isAbsolute() is sytem dependant. if I am running the code on windows it returns true for "C:/temp" but if I am referring to a unix path "/home/xx" , its returning false. In my code, am working with remote machine and I need to determine correctly is the file path is absolute or not. so i cant use this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java regex , to match a literal `\` symbol, you need to escape it three times. `(?i)` case insensitive modifier and this `[\\\\/]` matches a literal backslash or forward slash.

```
"(?i)^[a-z]:\\\\.*"
```

EXample:

```
System.out.println("C:\\temp".matches("(?i)[a-z]:\\\\.*"));   // true
System.out.println("C:/temp".matches("(?i)[a-z]:[\\\\/].*")); // true
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I passed "C:\temp" to test, but it still failed.

Comment: great, it worked, I was testing it wrong. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This should cover all your required cases:

```
"^(([a-zA-Z]:)?\\\\|/).*"
```

It matches paths starting (`^`) either (`|`) with

- a backslash (`\\\\`), optionally preceded by a letter and colon (`([a-zA-Z]:)?`); or
- a forward slash (`/`)

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. (I noticed that you have [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23766030/3558960) waiting to be accepted.)

Comment: I dont think i can accept two answers . although both are doing the job well.

Comment: Accepting whichever you prefer is perfectly fine.